# Analyzing workflow status, add sum, write workflow process in data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that contains a record of a workflow. It contains for each timestamp the status. So I do have time and day when something was done, however I sorted it in ascending order and this is sufficient for the next step, therefore this is not included in this sample data. My sample data looks like this (csv files are attached, [Example1.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SAttgENmj6TbNHUGBOemeivJoRvLt4Zq/view?usp=sharing) and [Example2.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rdDnGpiuGNinMX_f6CGzzqdh51iGtrne/view?usp=sharing), the preview in google looks wrong, as the decimal "," separator is not properly recognized):

[image: ex1]

So as I said these files are already sorted in ascending order and the status could be imagined as something like a workflow. So work started, proceed, finished, clean up. Like this:

[image: ex2]

Now I want to detect suspicious entries. For example if someone finished work without actually started it, or other unusual "patterns". What I would like to have is an overview of all the different workflows.

**1.**
I would like to have the counts / number of occurences per unique workflow. I achieved to implement this. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Example2.csv', sep=";", decimal=",", encoding="utf-8-sig")

df['Status']=df['Status'].astype(str)
df['Status'].fillna('No', inplace=True)

df=df.groupby(['Worker'])['Status'].apply('|'.join).reset_index()
df=df.groupby(['Status']).count()
df = df.rename(columns={'Worker': 'Count'})
#df['Sum']=df.groupby(['Amount']).sum()
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\outtest.csv', sep=';', encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Which works. I get the following output:

[image: output1]

or in case of using numbers:

[image: output2]

Which is exactly what I want. Here I can see for example that two workers started work and then directly cleaned up.

**2.**
Now I would like to have the sum of the amounts too. The amount per worker is always the same, so this number does not vary for a worker, so for example as shown in the sample data, worker 1 always has 2500,24. What I would like to have is this output:

[image: fo]

I tried to implement it with adding a simple line:

```
df['Sum']=df.groupby(['Amount']).sum()
```

But this throws an error. Reason is that the Amount in this step is simply not available. I could not figure out how to get this working.

How can I add the sum?

**3.**
I would like to "write the type of workflow which was counted for this worker" back to my original data file. So in my original data it should look like this (for simplicity reasons lets take the version where the status is represented with numbers):

[image: fo]

How can I implement this?

(I thought about this and it actually does not need to be combined with the results from my previous code. I just basically need to expand/transpose the status for each worker and write this to a new variable/column. However here the problem is that I do not know  in advance how many status/steps a worker has. So somehow I need to implement that "if the next entry belongs to the same worker than attach the value from status with a "|" to an existing variable" and this is my new column. But maybe I am wrong here and there is another implementation.)

Comment: Do you have an actual question? It isn't clear what you are trying to ask, seek help for.

Comment: My question is how to add the sum. Furthermore I would like to know how to achieve what I have written in my last part, how can I add a column containing the information what kind of workflow belongs to a worker.

Comment: You have a weird CSV file. You have 3 headers while 3 or 4 columns. See commas between sum and some number, while it should be semicolons.

Comment: My csv files are correct. As I have written in my post, it gets displayed wrongly in the preview with google cloud, as it does not recognize the ";" separator and "," decimal separator. In pandas this is not a problem and my code is correct, I specify it there.

Comment: Line `df=df.groupby(['Worker'])['Status'].apply('|'.join).reset_index()` vanishes `Amount` column and only `Worker` and `Status` are left. The correct way would be to create temp `frame` and reassign columns on `df` from the `frame`.

Comment: For me, this is too much info and, honestly, "How can I add this new column?" is a too simple question. Just add a column to your dataframe and then save it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller My question was not how to add a new column. My question is how to implement it, so how to add the column "workflow" which contains the workflow type.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The question is still too long, asks multiple questions at once and is very specific so that it's unlikely to help future readers. It seems you know how to do it manually. Just identify the each single step you do manually and implement that in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. To calculate `sum` of amounts we can first `groupby` the `Worker` column to get the workflow and the amount for each worker (I'm taking `first` for the amount since it's the same for all rows for the same worker). Then we `groupby` again on the workflow (which is in `Status` column after the first `groupby`), and calculate `count`s and `sum`s:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Example2.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
df['Status'] = df['Status'].astype(str)

z = df.groupby('Worker').agg({
    'Status': '|'.join,
    'Amount': 'first',
}).groupby('Status')['Amount'].agg(['count', 'sum']).reset_index()

# save and output
z.to_csv('outtest.csv', sep=';')
z
```

Output:

```
                                              Status  count      sum
0                                       Started work      1  2900.00
1                              Started work|Clean up      2  3600.18
2      Started work|Continued work|Finished|Clean up      2  6700.74
3  Started work|Continued work|Finished|Clean up|...      1  4200.98
```

3. To add workflow as a column, we can use `transform`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Example1.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
df['Status'] = df['Status'].astype(str)

# add workflow column
df['workflow'] = df.groupby('Worker')['Status'].transform('|'.join)

# save and output
df.to_csv('Example1_with_workflow.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
df
```

Output (using the numeric `Example1.csv` here to make it more readable, but will work with either of them, of course):

```
    Worker Status   Amount   workflow
0        1      1  2500.24    1|2|3|4
1        1      2  2500.24    1|2|3|4
2        1      3  2500.24    1|2|3|4
3        1      4  2500.24    1|2|3|4
4        2      1  2400.00        1|4
5        2      4  2400.00        1|4
6        3      1  4200.98  1|2|3|4|5
7        3      2  4200.98  1|2|3|4|5
8        3      3  4200.98  1|2|3|4|5
9        3      4  4200.98  1|2|3|4|5
10       3      5  4200.98  1|2|3|4|5
11       4      1  1200.18        1|4
12       4      4  1200.18        1|4
13       5      1  4200.50    1|2|3|4
14       5      2  4200.50    1|2|3|4
15       5      3  4200.50    1|2|3|4
16       5      4  4200.50    1|2|3|4
17       6      1  2900.00          1
```

P.S. If I read correctly, in (1) there was no question as everything worked as expected, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post, looks good and like I wanted. And yes (1) was clear. However, could you maybe post a full working example? So I don't know where I should insert your code and/if I should replace the other group by. I tried to insert your code instead of my group by statements, but I get an error. I think it it because I implemented your code into mine not properly. I also tried to add it after my groupby statements, but I get an error again.

Comment: Thanks for your update. However, when I run it now I just get the sum of amount as a column added, so counts are lost? I do not get your output.

Comment: We're talking (2), right? It should do both counts and sums (it does when I run it on `Example2.csv`)

Comment: Yes exactly, when I run it there is no count column in my resulting csv file? (the file is updated, date and time show it). I use df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\out1.csv', sep=';', encoding="utf-8-sig", index=False) to export it to a csv.

Comment: OK, yes, so we're not saving to a file, just printing it. I've added `to_csv` now, please check

Comment: And by the way, do you want to save the outputs of (2) and (3) to separate files? (because they're of course different levels -- (2) is per-workflow and (3) is per-action)

Comment: Thanks for your update, but how can I include (3) into your solution? It works now, but (3) is not included. No, one file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231743/discussion-between-perl-and-berthobe).